# Show or Hide a Listview on top of a webview

Tags: webview, youtube

The code below plays a link from you tube automatically and it's working fine. I just want to toggle (show/hide) the ListView so that I can select another link. The problem is that the listview quickly shows and then it hides.

```
 private void playYoutube(String lnk) {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        }
        webView.loadUrl(lnk);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click(); })()");
            }`your text`
        });
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (listview.isShown())
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried the above code but it shows the list view and then it hides.

Answer (score 0):

I just found one solution myself and it seems to work fine.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int eventAction = event.getAction();
                if (eventAction == 1 || eventAction == 2) {
                    if (eventAction == 1) {
            if (listview.isShown())
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```